# Get response after post camelContext

Tags: java, apache-camel

When I post in camel I get no response. The data is successfully processed, logged and posted without errors and warnings.

```
<camelContext id="camelId"  xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route id="pushItem" streamCache="true">
        <from uri="cxf:bean:pushItemCxfEndpoint" />
        <process ref="pushItemTransformer" />
        <log message="${body}"/>
        <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpMethod">
            <constant>POST</constant>
        </setHeader>
        <setBody>
            <simple>${body}</simple>
        </setBody>
        <to uri="http://endpoint/api/v1/products"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

I'd like to receive a response from http://endpoint/api/v1/products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```xml
<to uri="http://endpoint/api/v1/products"/>
<log message="Response code: ${in.header.CamelHttpResponseCode}"/>
<log message="Response text: ${in.header.CamelHttpResponseText}"/>
<log message="Response payload: ${body}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could place whatever you want to do with the response just after you have sent your http request

```
<to uri="http://endpoint/api/v1/products"/>
<log message="${body}"/>
```

Comment: The problem is I don't get a response at all. I have a 202 Accepted status code.

Comment: then try to set `synchronous=true`

Comment: Ok, I see your answer is also right. My ${body} after process has the same value as after post. thanks, my mistake.